# Unity - таймер в функции

Tags: unity3d, функции, таймер

Имеется простенький таймер:

```
TimeMinus -= Time.deltaTime;
if (TimeMinus < 0)
{
    money += 1000;          
}
```

Но проблема вот в чем: этот таймер должен вызваться в функции, которая срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку. Но так как функция отдельная от функции Update(), таймер идти не может, логично. И вот тут мне интересно, как тогда поступить? Хелп плиз

Comment: Попробуйте почитать про корутины.

Answer (score 3):

Для этой цели вам проще использовать корутину (Coroutine).

В вашем методе, который реагирует на нажатие кнопки нужно запустить корутину:
`StartCoroutine(MoneyTimer(1));//вместо 1 - время задержки до увеличения money (в секундах)`

далее код самой корутины:

```
IEnumerator MoneyTimer(float time)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    money += 1000;
}
```

p.s. ваш таймер плох тем, что даже если прикрутить его к `Update()`, то `money` будет **каждый кадр** (очень быстро и почти бесконечно) увеличиваться как только `TimeMinus` станет меньше 0 (конечно, если где-то в другом месте на такой случай не стоит "защита")